# Make all string methods use a custom comparer

Tags: c#, .net, string, dictionary, string-comparison

Is there a way to redefine all strings to use a customcomparer, for an entire project? Either with lots of extension methods or a custom string class? Is this a naive approach?

I have a custom string comparer that I use for some dictionaries, which support custom comparers, meaning:

```
SomeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(CustomComparer);
string someValue = SomeDictionary[somekey];//Uses Custom Comparison, not .Equals
```

I also made a extension method for contains, which I needed in some places, and you could use like this:

```
if(someString.Contains(key, new CustomComparer()))
    //Do Something
```

I just tried to this:

```
if(someString.Contains(key, new CustomComparer()))
    someString = someString.Replace("x", "y");
```

Since I didn't write an extension method for it, Replace() saw "X" in the actual string and said it wasn't equal to "x". I could make an extension for that too, but I fear this is a much bigger problem than I previously considered.

For reference, this is the extension method and the StringComparer

```
public static class Extensions
{
    //Very crude, just calls the CustomComparer directly, ignores the parameter comparer
    public static bool Contains(this string source, string match, StringComparer comp)
    {
        if (match == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Substring", "Substring cannot be null.");
        else
            return CustomComparer.ModifyString(source).Contains(match);
    }
}

public class CustomComparer : StringComparer
{
    public static Regex RemoveCharacters { get; set; } = new Regex(@"[\s-_(),.]+");

    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(ModifyString(x), ModifyString(y));
    }

    public override bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if (ModifyString(x).Equals(ModifyString(y)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return ModifyString(obj).GetHashCode();
    }

    public static string ModifyString(string s)
    {
        return RemoveCharacters.Replace(s.ToLowerInvariant().Trim(), string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you already doing that? Just have the extension method(s) at a level accessible to everything else in the project (maybe even a library of its own) and that's it?

Comment: @Sach My fear is that it is the naive solution, and that I would spend far more time making all those extension methods that doing something simpler. If no one has a better solution, then I will just do that.

Comment: @RufusL Yea, that makes sense. I wrote it kinda quickly with a plan to refactor it (I assumed this would come up), but then it never caused an issue until now.

Comment: In my opinion writing a custom `String` class would be a WAY bigger and unnecessary solution to a simpler problem. The extension methods are just that; an extension of something, and I feel like that's exactly you want. You want a little extended functionality to your `Equals` method, so you're writing a method to get the job done, which is the correct approach. For upper/lower case problem, you can simply include that check as a part of your `Equals` method so no need to add a different method. Simply, you just write a new extension when necessary and use what's available at other times.

Comment: So you mean, write an extension method for Replace, maybe do a bit of refactoring to make the methods consistent, but DON'T write an extension method for every string method now, do it over time? That is fast, and if you think it won't bite me later, then I'll trust your judgement. I'm still learning how to write code on this scale.

Comment: Well, yes. I mean, how can you write an extension method for every string method now, not knowing what you're going to need? The existing string methods do their job rather well as they are now, so you only really need to customize them when you actually have a need for extra functionality.